# What is the syntax of replace statement?

Tags: mysql, spring, jsp

This is my controller

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteMultiple", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView deleteEmp(@ModelAttribute("employee")  Employee emp,@RequestParam(value="Id",required=false) String Id,Model model) {
            List<Employee> empList = empService.getEmpList();
            List<Employee> empListById = empService.getemp_IdDetails(Id);
            empList=empService.searchEmpDetails(emp);
            empList.addAll(empListById);
              Employee emp1=new Employee();
                  if(empList!=null){
                      model.addAttribute("delete", empList);
                  if(empList.isEmpty()){
                     model.addAttribute("message","This Employee Details are not present");
                  }
                  }

                  model.addAttribute("employee", emp1);
                  return new ModelAndView("delete","empList",empList);
                  }
```

This is my sql

```
   @Override
     public List<Employee> getemp_IdDetails(String emp_Ids){
          List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();  
          String sql="select * from EmpDetails where emp_Id IN" + " ("+emp_Ids+") ";
          sql.replace("emp_Id", emp_Ids);
          JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource); 
          empList = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new EmployeeRowMapper()); 
          System.out.println("empList:"+empList.size());
          return empList; 
     }
```

This is my jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Drop down</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#delete").click(function(){
        var d = [];
        $.each($("#delete option:selected"), function(){            
           d.push($(this).val());
        });
        var s=(d.join(", "));
        console.log(s);
       $("#delete_empId").val(s);
       console.log($("#delete_empId").val());

    });
});
</script>
</head>  
<body>   

  <div align="center">
    <form:form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteMultiple" modelAttribute="employee">  
    <table>  
    <tr>  
      <td>First Name :</td>  
      <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>  
     </tr>  
     <tr>  
      <td>Last Name :</td>  
      <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>  
     </tr> 
     <tr>  
      <td>emp_Id :</td>  
      <td><form:input path="emp_Id" /></td>  
     </tr> 
     <tr>
      <td>email_Id :</td>
      <td><form:input path="email_ID"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>phone_No :</td>
      <td><form:input path="phone_No"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>City :</td>
      <td><form:input path="city"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>  
      <td> </td>  
      <td><input type="submit" value="Search" /></td>   
     </tr>  
    </table>  
  <input type= "hidden" id="delete_empId" name="delete_empId"  />

     </form:form>
</div>
  <div  align="center">  
  <h2 style="color:blue">SelectBox:</h2>
   <form:form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteMultipleEmpDetails">  
    <select id="delete"  multiple name="employees"> 
    <c:forEach items="${empList}" var="employee"> 
     <option value= "${employee.emp_Id}" >${employee.firstName}</option>
     ${msg}
    </c:forEach>
    </select> 
     <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">
    </form:form>
  </div>  
  <div>
         <h4 style="color:red">${message}</h4>  
    </div>

</body>  
</html>
```

This is my code i am retriving the values from jsp and passing the values to my controller.So i need to replace the values of emp_Id by emp_Ids.I have wriiten the replace function in sql is that coorect.I am getting null pointer exception.

Comment: Add the stacktrace please

Comment: Also replace a value in a string not values in db.

Comment: `sql.replace("emp_Id", emp_Ids);` what do you expect from this line?

Comment: `String sql="select * from EmpDetails where emp_Id IN" + " ("+emp_Ids+") ";` here you are inserting the id's but why do you want to replace the column name emp_Id with  `sql.replace("emp_Id", emp_Ids);`

Comment: I need to replace  a value.I am not getting that logic to replace values.